# Почему фамилия создателя русской фонетики должна писаться как Болдуэн де Куртенэ?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Напомню для мелкоплавающих в теме. Самым главным, самым важным  изданием И.А. Болдуэна де Куртенэ было и остаётся  третье академическое издание толкового словаря В.Даля. Фактически это его визитная карточка.

И вот в этом издании фамилия автора записана как Болдуэн. Кроме того, в документах полиции, когда он был посажен в тюрьму на 14 месяцев, он записан под фамилией Болдуэн. А то что глупые ученики Крушевский и Щерба извратили написание его фамилии, как раз и виновата в целом современная теория русского языка. Если, например, академик Лопатин В.В. утверждает, что в слове "ЁЖ" три звука - й,о и ш, то это не теория. Это уже диагноз.
Кстати, подготовленная мною к изданию "Бесспорная теория русского языка" уже в гораздо широком плане объясняет многие текущие научные недоразумения, которые всё ещё кто - то пытается выдавать за чистую монету. Думаю, многим русским филологам, распространяющим до сих пор текущую теорию русского языка совсем скоро  станет совсем стыдно .

К сожалению у меня нет права давать ответы , поскольку надо набрать 50 очков. Поэтому поступлю следующим возможным образом (может и увидите этот ответ):

Болдуэн - не поляк. Он отпрыск королевского рода иерусалимских королей.  И именно в такой транскрипции, например, современный историк Успенский пишет фамилии этой династии . Кроме того, современные докторские диссертации аспирантов кавказских республик также пишут эту фамилию. Просто надо уважать выбор человека - именно таким образом он сам себя называл. Думаю, это самый правильный подход в написании собственных имён, если прежде это имя было написано в другой графической системе.

Comment: Извините, пожалуйста, но это ваш вопрос похож на диагноз.

Comment: **Jan Niecisław Baudouin de Courtenay**
Прошу объяснить популярно, почему поляка де Куртенэ надо непременно именовать Болдуэном... Да, мы тут мелко плаваем!))) А Вашу теорию твердых и мягких звуков читаю на досуге, крайне интересно.

Comment: А сколько, по-вашему, звуков в слове ЕЖ?

Comment: ""**По родословной легенде,** происходил из древнего **французского** аристократического рода Куртене, ведущего свое начало от короля Людовика VI и к которому принадлежали, в частности, императоры Латинской (Римской) империи. В Польшу предок Бодуэна де Куртенэ переселился на рубеже XVII—XVIII веков"" (Вики)
Французское написание - **Baudouin**. Давайте завязывайте с Балдуинами (**Baldwin IV of Jerusalem**) , в русском дискурсе они как-то не звучат на серьезный лад. Иван Александрович Бодуэн де Куртенэ - выдающийся российский филолог, это гораздо круче иерусалимских временщиков Балдуинов!

Comment: ""Бодуэн де Куртене

После присоединения Польши ряды российских дворян пополнились родом Бодуэн де Куртене, который настаивал на происхождении от французских Куртене, хотя в настоящее время нет сведений, что документальные подтверждения этого родства были представлены общественности."" (Вики)

Comment: >современные докторские диссертации аспирантов кавказских республик   
  
Ага! Уже смешно. Аспиранты пишут докторские.   
Дэты, бол, сол и мол пышутса с мыагкым знаком, а вилька, лёжька и тарэлька - бэз нэго. Дэты, этого нэвозможно понат, это надо запомныт!

>"Бесспорная теория русского языка"   
  
Юноша, не принижайте свою гениальность. Пишите сразу "Общую теорию всего".

Comment: Меня заинтересовала теория Ивана Стрельцова.

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием почитал автореферат и пару-тройку научных рецензий. *Болдуэна* я считаю за легкий казус, а вот новая теория русского языка... Посмотрим! Иван Александрович, Вам - респект за смелость и настойчивость в продвижении своих идей, только тезку своего больше Балдуином не называйте, очень Вас прошу...

Comment: **Титульный лист** третьего издания словаря Даля.

""Третье, исправленное и значительно дополненное изданіе 

**подъ редакціею проф. И. А. Бодуэна-де-Куртенэ**

Томъ первый

А — З

изданіе

поставщиковъ Двора ЕГО ИМПЕРАТОРСКАГО ВЕЛИЧЕСТВА

товарищества М. О. Вольфъ

С.-Петербургъ , Гост. Дворъ, 18. | Москва , Кузнецкій Мостъ, 12.

**1903**""

Полицейских протоколов не нашел...

Comment: ![Титул](http://www.bookva.org/images/books/260_big.png?1327905453)

Answer (score 1):

А на основании чего, спрашивается, французский вариант имени надо заменять на германский? Только потому, что неграмотный околоточный вкупе с кавказскими аспирантами так пишут? Или они знают то, чего не знали глупые "ученики" с мировым именем? 
Кстати, прямым учеником ни один из них не был. Крушевский просто по возрасту не подходил, его называют просто (младшим) коллегой де Куртене, а со Щербой, насколько знаю, они всего лишь были в одно время в одном месте. Один преподавал, другой учился. Вряд ли это достаточное основание для признания одного учеником другого. Щерба - основатель и яркий представитель т.н. Ленинградской (Петербургской) фонологической школы, а де Куртене тяготел скорее даже Московской, сформировавшейся под сильным влиянием казанских идей.

Про Лопатина - это действительно диагноз. Но мы не специалисты, консультаций не даём.

Comment: Надо подключить к теории русских звуков хотя бы минимальные технические средства и выяснить всю их *подноготную* сущность! Кажется, еще в **Круге первом** занимались такой проблемой?

Answer (score 0):

А где и когда  можно ознакомиться с этой теорией?

Comment: >А где и когда можно ознакомиться с этой теорией?  
  
У главврача. Это не теория, это диагноз. Кавказские аспиранты вам в помощь.